# In Perl, how can I unpack to several variables?

Tags: perl, unpack

I have a struct wich contains:

```
struct mystruct{
  int                id[10];
  char               text[40];
  unsigned short int len;
};
```

And I'm trying to unpack it in a single line, something like this:

```
  my(@ids,$text,$length) = unpack("N10C40n",$buff) ;
```

But everything is going to the first array(@ids), i've tried templates as "**`N10 C40 n`**" and "**`(N10)(C40)(n)`**"
So, either this can't be done or I'm not using the proper template string.

**Note: I'm using big endian data.**

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In list assignment the first array or hash will eat everything (how would it know where to stop?).  Try this instead:

```
my @unpacked        = unpack "N10Z40n", $buff;
my @ids             = @unpacked[0 .. 9];
my ($text, $length) = @unpacked[10, 11];
```

you could also say

```
my @ids;
(@ids[0 .. 9], my ($text, $length)) = unpack "N10Z40n", $buff;
```

Comment: With that I'm not receiving C40 to $text, instead I'm geting first C to $text and second C to $length

Comment: Hmm, I had assumed your unpack was correct, let me take a quick look.

Comment: You probably want `A40` instead of `C40`.  `A40` is a space padded string of forty characters, `C40` is forty individual octets.  You may also want `Z40` which would be better in keeping with the idea that `text` is a C style string (i.e. a null terminate sequence of characters).

Comment: Could you update your correct answer with:
    my (@ids,$text,$length);
    (@ids[0 .. 9], $text, $length) = unpack ("N10Z40n", $buff);

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the `@ids` does not matter:

```
my ($length, $text, @ids) = reverse unpack("N10C40n",$buff) ;
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I had not considered that.

Comment: @Chas. It is likely to be inferior to your solution in terms of speed and but for small enough lists returned by `unpack`, it might be more straightforward.