# Destructuring using rest parameters in Perl

Tags: perl, variadic-functions, destructuring

I'm just getting started with Perl (5.38) and I recently learned how to destructure arguments from the argument array `@_`; for example: `my ($var1, $var2) = @_;`.

However, I wasn't able to find any information on using a rest parameter like we can in JavaScript, but it's entirely possible I was using search terms that were too specific to JS. For example, in JavaScript, you could do `function (var1, ...rest)`. Is there an equivalent way of doing something like `my ($var1, ...$rest) = @_;` in Perl? I did see this seemingly related post [In Perl, how can I unpack to several variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165099/in-perl-how-can-i-unpack-to-several-variables), but that seems overly complicated for this simple use-case, and I couldn't tell from an initial skim whether it can even be used for this situation, since the example was using structs.

**Note:** I'm looking specifically for a rest parameter equivalent, I know I can achieve the same thing by using slices, for example, but that requires multiple assignments (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: if signatures are used then you can do `sub fun($arg_1, @rest) { ... }`

Comment: @MustafaAydın ah interesting, thanks for mentioning. I thought that was a feature only in Raku, is that available (non-experimentally)in Perl v5.30?

Comment: hi, categorized nonexperimental from [36+](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-'signatures'-feature)

Comment: @MustafaAydın got it, unfortunately I found out while deploying that the target host only has 5.30, though I am using 5.38 in local dev, so I think this solution won't work for me. I assume it's not advisable to use experimental features in production Perl scripts?

Comment: I see, I have no production experience with Perl but from [what I read](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18537), i.e., it was vastly stable prior to 5.36, and given it's become nonexperimental, I would be using this specific feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
my ( $var1, @rest ) = @_;
```

It is also commonly written as follows:

```perl
my $var1 = shift;
my @rest = @_;
```